# Why are dataset(quakes) longitude values above 180?

Tags: r, ggmap

I wanted to use the built-in *quakes* dataset to demonstrate ggmap, however while trying to plot the points I kept getting an error. When I actually looked at the data, I was astonished to see that the longitude values were over 180:

```
> head(quakes)
     lat   long depth mag stations
1 -20.42 181.62   562 4.8       41
2 -20.62 181.03   650 4.2       15
3 -26.00 184.10    42 5.4       43
4 -17.97 181.66   626 4.1       19
5 -20.42 181.96   649 4.0       11
6 -19.68 184.31   195 4.0       12
```

As far as I know, these are impossible values (i.e. outside the -180 to 180 longitude range).

I missing something?

Comment: Apparently they're notating the longitudes with values in the range [0,360] rather than [-180,180].  You can convert the former to the latter by subtracting 360 if the longitude is greater than 180.

Comment: Jim L's almost certainly correct - you should be able to verify by seeing where these stations are located on the globe (i.e. by name and country).